# Dotnetnuke partial rendering make my jQueryUI widget stop working

Tags: jquery-ui, dotnetnuke, jquery-ui-tabs, renderpartial

I want to use tab widget of jQueryUI in dotnetnuke 5.6.3
I registered jQueryUI in my module and it works fine but when I use partial Rendering in my page it fails to load.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    rastaAdmin();
});
function rastaAdmin() {
var tabdiv = $('#tabul');
var tabvar = tabdiv.tabs();
}
```

[this site](http://www.shawnduggan.com/?p=102) have a method to solve my problem but it doesn't work in my script.

After reading the above site I changed my code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    rastaAdmin();
});
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    rastaAdmin();
}
function rastaAdmin() {
var tabdiv = $('#tabul');
var tabvar = tabdiv.tabs();
}
```

This Doesn't work for me.

What Can I do?

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had issues using the `pageLoad` function as well (though I don't remember now where it ended up breaking down).  However, something like the other method should work fine (see the new jQuery UI setup in the core modules in DNN 6):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setupDnnSiteSettings();
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () {
        setupDnnSiteSettings();
    });
});
```

The one caveat here is that this registers the setup code to happen after returning from *any* `UpdatePanel`-initiated request, not just your specific `UpdatePanel`.  Calling `tabs` again on the same element shouldn't cause any issue, but you'll want to figure out a way to differentiate if you're doing something that should only be called once.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you bdukes 
After your help, I changed my code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
Sys.Application.add_load(function (s, e) { rastaAdmin(); });
rastaAdmin();
});
function rastaAdmin() {
var tabdiv = $('#tabul');
var tabvar = tabdiv.tabs();
}
```

And It Works Like a charm for me! Thank You mate.